# NextJS v10 Image component fails to serve image when there is a basePath

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to migrate my app to the latest version of NextJS (v10). They've introduced a new Image Component (see [Release notes](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#built-in-image-component-and-automatic-image-optimization)) and when I try to use it, my app is unable to properly serve the images.

In my `next.config.js`, I've set a `basePath` value to be able to serve my app from a sub-path instead of root:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "mdx", "md"],
  basePath: "/an",
};
```

While this is set, `Image` component is not able to fetch my img file. Without it everything works perfectly, but my app is not served on `/an`

How I am supposed to define the `src` property while there is a `basePath` to be able to serve the images?

```
<Image
  src="/me.jpg" <-- This is not working with basePath
  alt="A photo of myself."
  className="rounded-full h-48 w-48 mx-auto"
  width="192"
  height="192"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21131) and [a PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22759) (as of writing this answer) here.

Meanwhile, as a workaround, (from the linked issue)

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

const basePath = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH;

const ImageWithBasePath: typeof Image = (props) => {
  const url = props.src?.startsWith('/')
    ? `${basePath || ''}${props.src}`
    : props.src;
  return <Image {...props} src={url}></Image>;
};

export default ImageWithBasePath;
```

export your `basePath` in env as `NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH` and replace the import `Image form 'next/image'` by `import ImageWithBasePath from './ImageWithBasePath'`

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is the issue, but you have to extract the className to the parent element like so

```
<div className="rounded-full h-48 w-48 mx-auto">
    <Image
      src="/me.jpg" <-- This is not working with basePath
      alt="A photo of myself."
      width="192"
      height="192"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: `Image` supports `className`